# %timeit tests run for variable number of loops for similar commands

Tags: python

Suppose such a data

```
In [51]: data = list(range(10**6))                                                                              

In [53]: data[-1]                                                                                               
Out[53]: 999999
```

Empirical test

```
In [54]: %timeit 999999 in data                                                                                 
13.8 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [55]: %timeit 5 in data                                                                                      
170 ns ± 55.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

I am very confused about 100 loops for 999999, but 10000000 loops for 5.

should the loops be identical on the both cases?

Comment: Because based on the timing, if your first test ran 10000000 times it would take 38 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `%timeit` with `ipython`, the module will limit the number of repetitions based on how long the script takes, so as to not have to loop through for an unreasonable amount of time. Because `5 in data` takes much less time than `999999 in data`, it is able to loop through many more times for the first case.

You can explicitely set the number of repetitions with the `-n` flag:

```
%timeit -n 5 999999 in data
16.3 ms ± 259 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 5 loops each)
```

Checking out the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html):

> Options: -n: execute the given statement  times in a loop. If  is not provided,  is determined so as to get sufficient accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

`timeit` tries to estimate the number of loops for you. As mentioned in the documentation:

> If -n is not given, a suitable number of loops is calculated by trying
>   successive powers of 10 until the total time is at least 0.2 seconds.

If you want to manually define the number of loops, use `number`:

```
import timeit    
timeit.timeit('999999 in range(10**6)', number=10000)
```

or from command-line interface, define `N` in `python -m timeit [-n N] [statement ...]`.